# Inter arrival times Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

$N_t$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda t$ . More generally, $N_{t+s}$ - $N_s$ is a
Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda t$ , independent of anything that has
occurred before time s .

Define $p_j(t)$ = $P(N_t = j)$, the probability that there have been exactly j events by time t is $\dfrac{e^{-\lambda t}{\lambda t}^j}{j!}$.

Since the Poisson process $N_t$ changes only by unit upward jumps, its sample
paths are fully characterised by the times at which the jumps take place. Denote
by $T_0 ,T_1,T_2,...$the successive inter-event times

- Apparently $T_0,T_1,T_2,...$ are a sequence of independent exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$

  #### Proof:

\begin{align}
P[T_1>t\mid T_0=s] & = P[N_{t+s} =1\mid T_0=s] \\[10pt]
& = P[N_{t+s}-N_s=0\mid T_0=s]\\[10pt]
& = P[N_{t+s}-N_s=0] =p_0(t) = \exp(-\lambda t)
\end{align}

Can someone please explain how the 2nd and 3rd lines come about in as simple a way as possible?

Comment: should those 2 lines involve $N_{t+s} - N_s$, not $N_t$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant that.

Comment: $T_0 = s$ is the time of the first event, so at that time $N=1$, i.e. $N_s = 1$.  This explains the 2nd line.  The 3rd line comes from your earlier observation that "More generally, $N_{t+s} - N_s$ is a Poisson random variable with mean λt , independent of anything that has occurred before time s ."